# linux php 7 configure: error: Please reinstall readline - I cannot find readline.h, but it is installed

Tags: php, linux, configure, php-7

I am compiling php7 from source and have pre compiled a number of dependencies in `/home/mybin` for example I have openssl in

```
   /home/mybin/bin/openssl
   /home/mybin/include/openssl/*.h
```

I have also readline as

```
/home/mybin/include/readline/readline.h
```

using the php compile options

```
./configure \
CC=/home/mybin/bin/gcc \
--prefix=/home/_cgi/php7 \
--bindir=/home/mybin/bin \
--libdir=/home/mybin/lib \
--with-libdir=/home/mybin/lib64 \
--includedir=/home/mybin/include \
--include-openssl \
```

i have tried the following options for readline

```
--with-readline=/home/mybin/include/readline
OR 
--with-readline=/home/mybin/
OR
--with-readline
```

all variations end with `configure: error: Please reinstall readline - I cannot find readline.h`

All other dependencies built from source and in `/home/mybin` are found no problem. Can you suggest what flag I sould set so `readline.h` can be found?

thx Art

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35891777/linux-correct-flag-to-pass-gcc-mcrypt-h-location for a good description of how to fix this issue as both are related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35891777/linux-correct-flag-to-pass-gcc-mcrypt-h-location for a good description of how to fix this issue as both are related

Answer (score 12):

On **Debian-9** first, I installed `libreadline-dev` package using

`apt-get install libreadline-dev`

and then when searching for the path of `readline.h` using command

`dpkg -S readline.h`

It gave me below output:

`nodejs: /usr/share/doc/nodejs/api/readline.html
 libreadline-dev:amd64: /usr/include/readline/readline.h`

So the file is located in `/usr` directory

Finally I configured `php` using `--with-readline=/usr` and everything was fine.

Answer (score 5):

for readline you need to install

`sudo apt install -y libedit-dev libreadline-dev`