# linux correct flag to pass gcc mcrypt.h location

Tags: php, c++, linux, gcc, php-7

I have compiled `libmcrypt` from source to `/home/mybin/...` with the following  confirmed as the location of the needed files.

```
/home/mybin/include/mcrypt.h
/home/mybin/include/mutils/mcrypt.h
/home/mybin/lib/libmcrypt.so ...> 4.4.8
/home/mybin/bin/libmcrypt-config
```

When I try a ./configure for php7 using the below options, I get an error message `configure: error: mcrypt.h not found. Please reinstall libmcrypt.`

What flags am I using incorrectly to tell gcc to look in the `../include` directory for `mcrypt.h`

```
./configure \
CC=/home/mybin/bin/gcc \
CPPFLAGS="-I/home/mybin/include" \
LDFLAGS="-L/home/mybin/lib" \
LIBS="-lmcrypt" \
--prefix=/home/_cgi/php7 \
--bindir=/home/mybin/bin \
--libdir=/home/mybin/lib \
--includedir=/home/mybin/include \
--with-mcrypt=/home/mybin/lib
```

from the `configure --help` I get

```
Some influential environment variables:
  CC          C compiler command
  CFLAGS      C compiler flags
  LDFLAGS     linker flags, e.g. -L<lib dir> if you have libraries in a
              nonstandard directory <lib dir>
  LIBS        libraries to pass to the linker, e.g. -l<library>
  CPPFLAGS    (Objective) C/C++ preprocessor flags, e.g. -I<include dir> if
              you have headers in a nonstandard directory <include dir>
  CPP         C preprocessor
  YACC        The `Yet Another Compiler Compiler' implementation to use.
              Defaults to the first program found out of: `bison -y', `byacc',
              `yacc'.
  YFLAGS      The list of arguments that will be passed by default to $YACC.
              This script will default YFLAGS to the empty string to avoid a
              default value of `-d' given by some make applications.
  CXX         C++ compiler command
  CXXFLAGS    C++ compiler flags
  CXXCPP      C++ preprocessor

  Fine tuning of the installation directories:
  --bindir=DIR            user executables [EPREFIX/bin]
  --sbindir=DIR           system admin executables [EPREFIX/sbin]
  --libexecdir=DIR        program executables [EPREFIX/libexec]
  --sysconfdir=DIR        read-only single-machine data [PREFIX/etc]
  --sharedstatedir=DIR    modifiable architecture-independent data [PREFIX/com]
  --localstatedir=DIR     modifiable single-machine data [PREFIX/var]
  --libdir=DIR            object code libraries [EPREFIX/lib]
  --includedir=DIR        C header files [PREFIX/include]
  --oldincludedir=DIR     C header files for non-gcc [/usr/include]
  --datarootdir=DIR       read-only arch.-independent data root [PREFIX/share]
  --datadir=DIR           read-only architecture-independent data [DATAROOTDIR]
  --infodir=DIR           info documentation [DATAROOTDIR/info]
  --localedir=DIR         locale-dependent data [DATAROOTDIR/locale]
  --mandir=DIR            man documentation [DATAROOTDIR/man]
  --docdir=DIR            documentation root [DATAROOTDIR/doc/PACKAGE]
  --htmldir=DIR           html documentation [DOCDIR]
  --dvidir=DIR            dvi documentation [DOCDIR]
  --pdfdir=DIR            pdf documentation [DOCDIR]
  --psdir=DIR             ps documentation [DOCDIR]

--with-mcrypt=DIR       Include mcrypt support
```

Comment: look at the config.log file around that error to see more information as to why the test failed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's see where this error comes from in the php7 source tree:

```
php-7.0.4$ grep -r 'mcrypt.h not found. Please reinstall libmcrypt'
ext/mcrypt/config.m4:    AC_MSG_ERROR(mcrypt.h not found. Please reinstall libmcrypt.)
configure:    as_fn_error $? "mcrypt.h not found. Please reinstall libmcrypt." "$LINENO" 5
```

We can ignore `configure` since it's a generated file, so it's from that `m4`
macro `ext/mcrypt/config.m4`. Let's look at the context:

```
...
if test "$PHP_MCRYPT" != "no"; then
  for i in $PHP_MCRYPT /usr/local /usr; do
    test -f $i/include/mcrypt.h && MCRYPT_DIR=$i && break
  done

  if test -z "$MCRYPT_DIR"; then
    AC_MSG_ERROR(mcrypt.h not found. Please reinstall libmcrypt.)
  fi
...
```

Now all becomes clear. If `$PHP_MCRYPT` isn't "no" then its the
value of `DIR` as per `--with-mcrypt[=DIR]`, i.e. a directory
path or nothing.

If it's nothing then `mcrypt.h` is looked for in:

- `/usr/local/include` (`libmcrypt` was installed by a default `make install`)
- `/usr/include` (`libmcrypt` was installed by the distro package manager)

If it's not nothing then `mcrypt.h` is additionally (and for preference) looked
for in:

- `$PHP_MCRYPT/include` (`libmcrypt` was installed by a non-default `make install` to `$PHP_MCRYPT`)

So if you specify `--with-mcrypt=DIR`, then `DIR` should be your *installation
prefix for* `libmcrypt`, *not the directory containing* `libmcrypt.so`.

So your solution is, change:

```
--with-mcrypt=/home/mybin/lib
```

to:

```
--with-mcrypt=/home/mybin
```

Comment: Thank you for what I think is the best answer I have ever received on SO.  It is clear, descriptive and above all without a hint of condescension. I had tried several combinations of options and the `--with-mcrypt=/home/mybin` worked, however also using `--with-libdir=DIR` caused it to fail. Removing the `--with-libdir` enables the other `--with-xxx` to work as you have described as well, including my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35879203/linux-php-7-configure-error-please-reinstall-readline-i-cannot-find-readline. Thx Art.

Comment: That you for that. Make it worthwhile ;)